# What does a sequence of retransmissions with PSH,ACK flags mean (and a spurious retransmission back)?

Tags: linux, networking, wireshark, tcpdump

I am on server `192.168.0.2` and want to make an HTTP call to `192.168.0.1`(both servers are RPis and run Linux (raspbian)).

```
curl -XGET http://192.168.0.1:8081/api
```

The API on `192.168.0.1` (which I am calling) is mine (a Python script based on `bottle`) and works most of the time.  The HTTP listening part sometimes mysteriously hangs, which results with the `curl` call above hanging, then timing out.

I ran `tcpdump` on 192.168.0.1 (the receiving server, the one which hosts the API) when the API was non responsive and the `wireshark` analysis shows some retransmissions right after the call is initiated:

[image]

**What is usually the cause of such behaviour?** (if there is a "usual" cause).

Note 1: If needed, I will modify the API so that it logs more data for the webserver part but due to the non-reproducible nature of the hang, I doubt that it is its fault (the other pieces (threads) work great and there is no crash of any thread).

Note 2: rebooting the server (also probably restarting the script itself (which I do not do as I rather reboot the machine)) fixes the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **What does a sequence of retransmissions with PSH,ACK flags mean (and a spurious retransmission back)?**
>
> What is usually the cause of such behaviour? (if there is a "usual"
>   cause).

### [**PSH ACK Wireshark Trace**](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/20423/pshack-wireshark-capture)

(Also See ***[ServerFault - PHA ACK During My
   Connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/614590/what-is-psh-ack-doing-during-my-connection-to-a-global-catalog-server)***)

> ACK means that the machine sending the packet with ACK is
>   acknowledging data that it had received from the other machine. In
>   TCP, once the connection is established, all packets sent by either
>   side will contain an ACK, even if it's just re-acknowledging data that
>   it's already acknowledged.
>
> PSH is an indication by the sender that, if the receiving machine's
>   TCP implementation has not yet provided the data it's received to the
>   code that's reading the data (program, or library used by a program),
>   it should do so at that point. To quote RFC 793, the official
>   specification for TCP:
>
> The data that flows on a connection may be thought of as a stream of
>   octets. The sending user indicates in each SEND call whether the data
>   in that call (and any preceeding calls) should be immediately pushed
>   through to the receiving user by the setting of the PUSH flag.
>
> A sending TCP is allowed to collect data from the sending user and to
>   send that data in segments at its own convenience, until the push
>   function is signaled, then it must send all unsent data. When a
>   receiving TCP sees the PUSH flag, it must not wait for more data from
>   the sending TCP before passing the data to the receiving process.

---

### [Spurious Retransmissions](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2013/06/spurious-retransmissions/comment-page-1/)

> If you’re seeing spurious retransmissions it means that the sender
>   thought packets were lost and sent them again, even though the
>   receiver sent an acknowledge packet for it.

---

### **Possible Causes**

- A misconfiguration between the server and client machines
- A misconfiguration between any sender and receiver anywhere along the hop path the of TCP packets
- Firewall rules or packet filters blocking packets

### Additonal Troubleshooting

- Check the server logs when this occurs as well
- Run the TCP trace with Wireshark on the server to see what those packets look like when the problem occurs

Comment: I am having the same issue but the difference is that only google is not opening but everything else is. I am connected to my mobile hotspot and this problem only persists on this hotspot (that too not always, but a lot of times)